# I have a brother, who's almost like me. Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word

> I have a brother, who's almost like me, but not quite.
>
> We have distant relatives too, but they live far away.
>
> I live in equilibrium, just like you, but completely differently.

**Who am I?**

**Hint:**

> I am quite lonely. Rarely anyone visits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first thought was

> the north and south poles

> I have a brother, who's almost like me, but not quite: North Pole and South Pole

> We have distant relatives too, but they live far away: Other planets have north and south poles, but they are very far away

> I live in equilibrium, just like you, but completely differently: The poles are in balance, but one is on land, the other in the sea.

They seem to meet the requirements of all 3 sentences.

Comment: ROT13(Pna lbh rkcynva gur zrnavat oruvaq rnpu fragrapr? Vs fb, V'yy znex vg nf npprcgrq.)

Answer (score 1):

I would say you are the

> boy/man from the twins paradox.

Comment: How would that explain sentence 2 and 3?

Comment: Well, if I'm the twin that is traveling through space, then all my relatives are on earth, quite far away.
About the equilibrium, I thought it could be related to a different amount of gravity in the spaceship.

Comment: Sorry, but our answer is in another castle.